# ng-repeat into rows without using boostrap

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I once again turn to StackOverflow for help on this one. I am fully aware how to do this with Bootstrap, however I would like to do it only with Ionic if possible (not been able to find anything focusing just on this).

**Problem**: I would like to use ng-repeat to divide create a new row if an array has more than 3 entries.

**Code Example (with attempt)**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas">
        <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul name="{{data.name}}">
                <li>
                    <img class="drinks-placeholder" data-ng-src="img/{{data.image}}">
                </li>
                <li>{{data.option1}} - {{data.option2}} </li>
                <li>{{data.detail}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the content being row wise, and not splitting after 3 displays. I suspect I need to flip the row class but I am not sure the best way to approach this.

Any suggestions greatly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used float left to the blocks and I just added ng-style with condition to the div which has ng-repeat. It's working as you expected. You can refer below the plunkr [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ty2GJMhXxbLVayQme9MQ?p=preview)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="MyController">
      <div ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-style="$index % 3 === 0 ? {'float': 'left', 'clear': 'both'} : {'float': 'left'}">
        <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0"></div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul name="{{data.name}}">
            <li>
              <img class="drinks-placeholder" data-ng-src="img/{{data.image}}" />
            </li>
            <li>{{data.option1}} - {{data.option2}} </li>
            <li>{{data.detail}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var module = angular.module("myApp", []);
      module.controller("MyController", ['$scope', function(scope){
        scope.datas = [
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'},
          {name: 'dog', image: '', option1: '1', option2: '2', detail: 'It is a dog'}
        ];
      }]);
      
    </script>
  </body>
  
  

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure either, but I guess you'd like to split your array of options into rows, each containing 3 columns - am I correct?

I've prepared a little playground example right here, have a look:
http://play.ionic.io/app/d67b4f541216

Core idea is the splitDatas function:

```
/**
 * Split the datas array into cols and rows
 */
$scope.splitDatas = function( columns ){

    var toSplit = angular.copy($scope.datas);
    $scope.splittedDatas = [];

    if ( columns === undefined )
      columns = 3;

    while ( toSplit.length > 0 ) {
      $scope.splittedDatas.push( toSplit.splice(0, 3) )
    }

}
```

In short the approach is to take the array and split it into a two-dimensional array, first dimension containing all the rows, second the columns though.

Keep in mind that each time you modify your datas array, you have to call the split function again, to apply the changes to your splitted array as well.

Hope this helps! ;)